# How to activate touchpad while typing?

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, touchpad

Since I upgraded to 17.10, it seems that the touchpad of my laptop is automatically deactivated while I'm typing. This is inconvenient for some applications, e.g., videogames. I'm not 100% sure the problem appeared with 17.10, but I never noticed it before.

I don't see any "deactive touchpad while typing" option in the Settings/Devices/Mouse & Touchpad menu.

I tried the GNOME Shell extension "Touchpad indicator" but it doesn't provide this option either, so I disabled the extension.

I followed the instructions on https://itsfoss.com/disable-touchpad-when-mouse-used/ to install "touchpad-indicator", but the program doesn't launch. When I try it in the command line, I get.

```
[00:06:~]$ touchpad-indicator 
<gettext.GNUTranslations object at 0x7f895d439d30>
No LSB modules are available.
#####################################################
Distributor: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 17.10
Release: 17.10
Codename: artful
Architecture: x86_64
#####################################################

Touchpad-Indicator version: 2.0.4-0extras18.04.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/touchpad-indicator", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/share/touchpad-indicator/touchpadindicator.py", line 707, in main
    TouchpadIndicator()
  File "/usr/share/touchpad-indicator/touchpadindicator.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.read_preferences(is_on_start=True)
  File "/usr/share/touchpad-indicator/touchpadindicator.py", line 344, in read_preferences
    tipo = self.touchpad._get_type(self.touchpad._get_ids()[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'd like to *not* deactivate the touchpad when I type. (Or ideally have a graphical menu that allows me to control this behaviour manually.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing false
```

Comment: worked like a charm.